# CSS y javascript vaciar el contenido de un campo

Tags: javascript, css, validación, transacciones, innerhtml

estoy tratando de validar un campo de email, mostrando un mensaje de error si el email no está bien introducido (con transición).

Si el email es correcto o el input está vacío el mensaje desaparece pero el contenido permanece.

He probado con `inerHTML = ""` pero la transición deja de funcionar. ¿Que podría hacer para vaciar el contenido? Gracias de antemano.

```js
const email = document.querySelector('#email');

eventListeners();

function eventListeners() {
  email.addEventListener('keyup', validateEmail);
}

function validateEmail() {

  const email = document.querySelector('.email'),
    error = document.querySelector('.error'),
    inputEmail = document.querySelector('#email'),
    formatEmail = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  if (inputEmail.value.match(formatEmail)) {
    error.classList.remove("show");
  } else {
    if (inputEmail.value !== "") {
      error.innerHTML = `<p>error</p>`;
      error.classList.add("show")
    } else {
      error.classList.remove("show");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.error {
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #d5d5d5;
  text-align: center;
}

.show {
  max-height: 100px;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="email">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  <div class="error"></div>
</div>
<div class="password">
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
```

Comment: como quieres conservar tu animación y la haces desde el css, lo que pudieras hacer es agregar un timeout, donde remueves la clase show, y agregar tu linea de el innerHtml.

Comment: @Eduardo Jaramillo Licea Es una buena solución gracias. Pero ya que lo mencionas, ¿ Como podria animar ese mensaje desde javascript ? ¿serias tan amanle de mostrarme un ejemplo aplicado al codigo? Se que se puede pero estoy empezando a programar y no sabria como hacerlo, un saludo.

Comment: No es necesario "limpiar" con `innerHTML`, basta con que agregues o elimines la clase para que funcione.

Answer (score 0):

Seria bueno que en vez de Keyup lo cambias a Change, ya que los métodos funcionan al quitar el focus en el input o al termino de hacer un cambio en este

```js
const email = document.querySelector('#email');

eventListeners();

function eventListeners() {
  email.addEventListener('change', validateEmail);
}

function validateEmail() {

  const email = document.querySelector('.email'),
    error = document.querySelector('.error'),
    inputEmail = document.querySelector('#email'),
    formatEmail = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  if (inputEmail.value.match(formatEmail)) {
    error.classList.remove("show");
  } else {
    if (inputEmail.value !== "") {
      error.innerHTML = `<p>error</p>`;
      inputEmail.value = ''
      error.classList.add("show")
    } else {
      error.classList.remove("show");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.error {
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #d5d5d5;
  text-align: center;
}

.show {
  max-height: 100px;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="email">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  <div class="error"></div>
</div>
<div class="password">
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
```

Saludos!